how to load the word add in react extension without a clicking extension icon when we open a document on initial load in word application [office js]
how to load the word add in extension without a clicking extension icon when we open a document on initial load in word application [word add in react office js].
please share me the implementation for this functionality in add in react .
I have already tried Office.addin.setStartupBehavior but this is not working as for my scenario.
